# Qual é a origem da expressão «aque-d’el-rei»?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica, expressões-idiomáticas

Aqui no norte de Portugal costuma-se usar bastantes vezes essa expressão, como por exemplo:

> Vais andar de bicicleta sem proteção e depois é «aque-d’el-rei» porque te
>   aleijas.

A ideia da expressão é identificar um grito de um pedido de ajuda. Corrijam-me se estiver enganado.

Qual é a origem dessa expressão?

Comment: Sempre pensei que fosse "aqui d'el rei", mas parece que "aque d'el rei" é uma alternativa reconhecida. Curioso...

Comment: @ANeves sim são as duas reconhecidas pelo que sei, aqui usa-se «aque»

Comment: Tem a certeza de que existe a palavra "aque"? Vivo no norte de Portugal há 70 anos e não me lembro de ver escrito assim. Nem no Fernão Lopes. Pode no entanto ser uma forma local, não fazendo parte do padrão geral.

Comment: AS minhas vizinhas quando estavam aflitas diziam "Aqui del Rei"

Answer (score 3):

Antigamente, um pedido para ser acudido pelos homens (soldados) do Rei, ou seja por agentes da lei. Usava-se, unicamente, em casos onde havia reais ou pretensas infrações à lei.

O uso citado acima é uma extensão do uso original.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo de uso?