# As expressões "Acuda del rei "e "aqui del rei " têm o mesmo significado?

Tags: significado, expressões

"Acuda del rei "e "aqui del rei " têm o mesmo significado ?

Ouvia os meus vizinho utilizarem a expressão "Acuda del rei " há muitos anos atrás .
Agora entrou em desuso

Comment: Olha que "acuda del rei" tem 1 única ocorrência no google, tenho dúvidas que a expressão seja usada.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qual é a origem da expressão «aque-d’el-rei»?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4503/qual-%c3%a9-a-origem-da-express%c3%a3o-aque-d-el-rei)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez, eles tivessem dito "Acuda meu rei", que deve ser "Me ajude". Devem ser baianos porque"rei", seu eu não me engano, é um termo usado muito na Bahia para se referir a uma pessoa.